# Output a random OEIS sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, random, internet

Your challenge: Connect to the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences [OEIS.org](http://oeis.org), access any random valid sequence, output it's ID, and ouput all of the members of the sequence provided by the OEIS entry. The *only* website you're allowed to connect to is OEIS.org.

Hints: Sequences are found in URLs such as http://oeis.org/A280629, however a more easily parseable version is found at URLs such as http://oeis.org/search?q=id:A280629&fmt=text. Every present *and future* sequence matches the regex `"[A-Z]\d{6}"`. (The regex is there to describe what an ID looks like. There are a lot of invalid sequences that match it, too). The webcam (http://oeis.org/webcam) feature of OEIS generates random sequences, but you'll have to find a way to change the dropdown menu from 'best sequences' to 'all sequences' to use it.

Example output:

```
A280629
1, 1, 7, 139, 6913, 508921, 57888967, 9313574419, 1984690709953, 547467006437041, 188946742298214727, 79783392959511537499, 40498043815904027702593, 24314800861291379306213161, 17047720745682515427867108487, 13802952030641885344209574247779, 12780883488499783875309105315925633, 13420910251496135926622603184056054881, 15863354775169518855398667975850797997447, 20966527201075972453953302254528386060431659
```

Every existing sequence has to have a chance of being outputed, it does not have to be an equal chance.

Your program should continue to function properly regardless of future sequences being added. Even though all IDs presently start with A, there will eventually be a sequence B000001 after all the A sequences run out. You can assume that there will be no more sequences after Z999999 is defined, but you do have to assume that it *will* eventually be defined.

An invalid sequence, which your program should never output, is one that doesn't exist. You may treat sequences with no given members (such as [A280611](http://oeis.org/A280611) either as invalid or give just the sequence ID and nothing else or a falsy value, but you must be consistent.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), fewest bytes wins!

Comment: Your regex isn't quite right - sequences can't end with `000000`. Additionally, is outputting a valid sequence that doesn't exist yet acceptable?

Comment: What about "sequences" like [this one](http://oeis.org/search?q=id:A280611&fmt=text). How shall we handle those? Do we have to check if the entry contains a sequence, and if not find another entry that does? This makes it a lot harder/cumbersome.

Comment: When the sequences names have leading 0, can we omit those 0? (for instance, `A15` instead of `A000015`)

Comment: Arg, this is impossible in JS

Comment: @StewieGriffin That one now has member, so one can't fall to it when fail. OP should say if this fine though

Comment: @TrojanByAccident, [Oh, no it's not](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255539/58974)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Perl, 93 bytes

```pl
$u=chr(65+rand 26).sprintf("%06d",rand 1e6),$_=`curl oeis.org/$u`while!/tt>(.*?)</;say"$u
$1"
```

Run it with `-E` flag (and I suggest redirecting `STDERR`, as `curl` prints its progression on it):

```
perl -E '$u=chr(65+rand 26).sprintf("%06d",rand 1e6),$_=`curl oeis.org/$u`while!/tt>(.*?)</;say"$u
$1"' 2> /dev/null
```

Explanations:
-`$u=chr(65+rand 26).sprintf("%06d",rand 1e6)` generates a random name,
-`$_=curl oeis.org/$u` tries to retrieve the sequence,
-`/tt>(.*?)</` checks if a tag `<tt>` is present on the page (it's only present on valid pages). If so, it stores the sequence's elements in `$1`. And if not, the `while` keeps looping.
-`say"$u\n$1"` outputs the sequence's name and its elements.

Comment: Do you know of an online interpreter where this works?

Comment: The easiest is to run it in a unix terminal... It does potentially a lot of http request, so I don't think there is an online interpreter capable of running it..

Comment: This actually fails for http://oeis.org/A280611 ...

Comment: @TrojanByAccident I don't think it does: replace `$u=chr(65+rand 26).sprintf("%06d",rand 1e6)` by `$u=A280611` and you'll have the right output...

Comment: @Dada well, I'm no expert on Perl, and I can't run it, as I'm on Windows, but that page contains `<tt>` tags, so...

Comment: @TrojanByAccident The challenge says `You may treat sequences with no given members (such as A280611 either as invalid or give just the sequence ID and nothing else`. My code will output only the sequence name in that case, which follows the rules...

Comment: @Dada ah, sorry, as I said, I don't know much about Perl, I was just going by your explanation

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, <strike>221</strike>,208 bytes

```python
from requests import*
from random import*
import re
r=randint
g=lambda x:re.findall(r'(?<=tt>)[^<]*',get('https://oeis.org/'+x).text)
a=''
while not g(a):a=chr(r(65,90))+str(r(0,999999))
print(a+'\n'+g(a)[0])
```

I'm sure there's a few tricks I missed (and requests is an external lib), but this was a fun first go at python code golf

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer! Could `b` be inlined? It only seems to be used in one place

Comment: Good catch! Was a holdover from when I had structured it slightly differently

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 104 bytes

Because [someone commented](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/106068/output-a-random-oeis-sequence#comment257935_106068) that this isn't possible in JS!

Must be run from the root directory of OEIS ([consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13938/if-we-can-require-a-particular-domain-can-we-require-a-particular-path)). Returns a 2-element array, with the first element being the sequence number and the second the sequence itself.

```javascript
f=async n=>(s=/tt>[^<]+/.exec(await(await fetch(n+=Math.random()*1e6|0)).text()))?[n,s[0].slice(3)]:f`A`
```

To test it, go to the [OEIS homepage](http://oeis.org/) (or any sequence's page), open your browser's console and copy & paste the code below:

```javascript
f=async n=>(s=/tt>[^<]+/.exec(await(await fetch(n+=Math.random()*1e6|0)).text()))?[n,s[0].slice(3)]:f`A`
await f()
```

### 97 bytes

This *should* work and could maybe be golfed a little further but I'm on my phone so can't test it properly.

```javascript
f=async n=>(s=/(?<=tt>)[^<]+/.exec(await(await fetch(n+=Math.random()*1e6|0)).text()))?[n,s]:f`A`
```

Comment: Count the URL you need to go, to avoid encoding program in URL

Comment: @l4m2, see the consensus I _very deliberately_ linked to in order to avoid comments like yours. See also the consensus linked from that one.

Comment: The link isn't answered